# How to get winter hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I am seeing different profiles having hats on their profile, even I want to grab one. Does it need special privileges, more points ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to achieve any one of the actions as listed [here](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) to wear the hats.

> Stack Exchange invites you to celebrate the end of a great year …with
>   HATS! As you use your site, you'll discover hats and other items
>   hidden behind certain actions. Collect all of them, some of them, or
>   none of them, but be quick – the hats get put back in their boxes on
>   January 4th!

Comment: thanks Bala, I was there on the link you shared, unfortunately every box turns out with "You haven't earned this hat on any sites yet." even for Hi Ho Silver which I guess ask for silver badge,which I guess I have.Anyway I am targeting for Ho Ho Ho,Christmas bonus :)

Comment: @arpitr you need to achieve during the period 16-12-2013 to 4-01-2014, otherwise you can not get any hat, even if you already earned badges. If you earn within this period you will earn a new hat!!

Comment: I missed that :)

Comment: @arpitr you can also check your rank here http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: I love my hats it was a great idea :D